# Problem add contact form 7

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

How can include a contact form 7 
in other page? of the theme  and add style with CSS
Are a include or something??

This code works fine ?? 
http://pastebin.com/Ffq3Uw7J
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just test? We don't know in which context you call that snippet, so please don't ask.

Comment: the code works fine , but I need to add css of this code?? how can do that http://pastebin.com/nfmk4x5E

Comment: @Felipe, you need to accept answers to the questions you ask, that's how this site works. Also, try to narrow down to a specific the problem before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page template, include any css you want in the new page template.
Please visit this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates)